# Unity: Texture is Blotchy using Unity Store TSF

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blender

- [Problem](http://prntscr.com/e5pf4q)
- [Material Properties](http://prntscr.com/e5pgp9)
- [Object Properties](http://prntscr.com/e5pgxv)

The Mesh was made in blender and the game is in Unity 5. It seems to work Fine with the Regular Shade so it might be a problem with the [Unity Store TSF](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21288)